# ¿cómo puedo comparar una lista de fechas para traer la más reciente?

Tags: python, pyspark, amazon-s3

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
archivos = s3.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    Prefix= "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
)
if archivos.get('Contents') != None:
    for archivo in archivos['Contents']:
        print(archivo['LastModified'])
```

Estoy tratando de eliminar los archivos más antiguos de mi bucket ¿como puedo comparar las lista de fechas de creación para determinar cual es la más reciente?

Comment: ordénalas de mayor a menor y escoges la primera

Comment: Tienes una lista de fechas ... lo único relevante es el formato de las fechas. No conozco S3 ... ¿qué se supone que retorna `archivo['LastModified']`? ¿String, un número, un objeto?